# Real world coordinate tracking problem between positive/negative infinity.

Tags: linear-transformations, asymptotics, coordinate-systems, transformation, infinity

I am an engineer working on a steering system with many wheels.  In order to steer correctly, the wheels must all be oriented perpendicular to a single point.  So if the wheels were in a tight turn, their configuration might look something like this:

[image]

With the red dot representing the center steer point that all the wheels are perpendicular to.  I track this point as the wheels make turns to ensure that they stay in sync, using a cartesian coordinate system.  As the wheels are turned straighter, the steer point moves away from the wheels:

[image]

However, there is a problem when transitioning from a right turn to a left turn and vice versa.  As the wheels approach parallel in such a turn, the steer point moves away from the wheels an infinite distance until the wheels are parallel, at which time there is not a valid steer point.  As the wheels pass through parallel, the steer point jumps from infinity in one direction to the infinity 180° in the other direction.

This problem makes it impossible to smoothly track the steer point in the cartesian coordinate system.  Is there a transform that I can use to another coordinate system that will allow me to track this steer point without the discontinuity?

Are there other tags I should use on this question?  I'm not quite sure what branch of mathematics would be most applicable.

Comment: Instead of orienting all of the wheels toward a steering point, you could make all of the wheels have the same angle to each other. They are equivalent, but angles don't turn undefined.

Comment: Instead or the radius consider the inverse radius $1/r$ (the curvature) and treat the two sides of the vehicle as positive or negative.